Convert datetime64 data to datetime in python
I downloaded a dataset with time data in datetime64 type, I need it in a format where each date value is separated into year, month and day as different elements. How can I do that?
As reference, this is one element, I need something like (2010, 1, 1), hour, minutes, etc don't matter:
tiempo[0]
Out[207]: numpy.datetime64('2010-01-01T12:00:00.000000000')

I tried converting it to timestamp and then to datetime, but I couldn't make it work.
ts = (tiempo - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'))// np.timedelta64(1, 's')


you can use pandas to_datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tiempo = np.datetime64('2010-01-01T12:00:00.000000000')
date_time = pd.to_datetime(tiempo)
print(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.day)


The datetime built-in can be used to parse a date string. This saves having to faff around with the .astype conversions and the associated epoch math.
A caveat to this is the strptime method can only parse fractional seconds to six decimal places. Therefore, the nine decimal place string needs to have the trailing three zeros trimmed.
Clean and simple:
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Original numpy datetime object.
npdt = np.datetime64('2010-12-01T12:00:00.000000000')
# Parsed datetime object.
dto = dt.strptime(npdt.astype(str)[:-3], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
# Tuple containing (year, month, day)
date = dto.year, dto.month, dto.day

Output:
(2010, 12, 1)


How about something like this:
import numpy as np

tiempo = np.datetime64('2010-01-01T12:00:00.000000000')

year = tiempo.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int) + 1970
month = tiempo.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1
day = tiempo.astype('datetime64[D]').astype(int) % (365 // 12) + 1

print(year, month, day)


One way to do this:
from dateutil.parser import parse

def to_date(dt):
    return parse(str(dt)).date()

And then apply this function to all elements of your dataset.
Assuming tiempo is pandas Series, you can get dates like this:
dates = tiempo.apply(to_date)

If you expect None in the input (i.e. NULL was in the database), better do this:
dates = tiempo.apply(lambda x: pd.NaT if x is None else to_date(x))


to_date function will work correctly not only with np.datetime64, but with any 'date-like' type. Timestamp, datetime, date, etc., even string representation of dates in various formats.
